# Have spin-correlation experiments been done on entangled particles other than photons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, bells-inequality, non-locality

I know that Bell experiments on spin correlations have been done with entangled photons, but have spin-correlation experiments ever been done on entangled particles other than photons?

Comment: <a href="https://www.nature.com/articles/35057215"> Here </a> is an example.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia has a nice [list of Bell tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_test), not all of them are about entangled photons:

- Rowe et al. (2001): Bell test with entangled trapped ions.
- Ansmann et al. (2009): Bell test using superconducting qubits separated by some milimiters
- Hensen et al., Giustina et al., Shalm et al. (2015):  they entangled electrons in NV centers using a photonic link.
- Schmied et al. (2016): entanglement of particles of a Bose-Einstein condensate